# Set default value of select if no value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this `select` :

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.users(), optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: $root.selectedUser, optionsCaption: 'Select one'"></select>
```

I only need the default value ('Select one') to be selected if `$root.selectedUser = 0` otherwise I don't need the default value.

I tried that:

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.users(), optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: $root.selectedUser, optionsCaption: $root.selectedUser () === 0 ? 'Select one' : ''"></select>
```

But it's not working. (if `$root.selectedUser = 0` it shows the first value of the list instead of the default value.)

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error:  http://jsfiddle.net/ogLpxc0L/1/.  Could you update the fiddle, please?

Comment: @JoseLuis Thank you, I found what causes the issue: `selectedUser` can't get a `0` value, when I set it with a `0` value it gets `undefined`. Why `selectedUser` can't be `0`? I added a `console.log() to the fiddle.

Comment: In this update of the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ogLpxc0L/4/) you can select the '0'.  I added a row, `Selected`, to show the actual value selected.  Also, I changed the first user to have id = 0.  In this link (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) it says that `undefined` value shows the default option.

Comment: @JoseLuis That means that `value` can't get a value that is not one of the options of the `select`, I managed to solve it, if you want you can write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this ModelView:

```
    var User = function(id, name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    };

    var viewModel = {
        users : ko.observableArray([
            new User(0,"User 1"),
            new User(2,"User 2"),
            new User(3,"User 3")
        ]),
        selectedUser : ko.observable(0)
    };


    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I have an User that has Id 0.

If you save in your observable any value that is an Id, it selects this option.  All of this will select one option:

```
 selectedUser : ko.observable(0)
 selectedUser : ko.observable(2)
 selectedUser : ko.observable(3)
```

If you save any value, or `undefined`, then the default option is showed.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ogLpxc0L/4/) shows this example.

Comment: Glad to help !! :-)